# How to capture (initialisation) errors from a cross-domain iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cors, cross-domain

I'm setting up a micro-frontend solution which contains the main integration app which resides in the main window and a bunch of iframes with services (sub apps). This services are SPA's but not necessary and are served from another domains but I can control them. The main app needs to get some configuration from underlying services and it works the following way - the couple of embedded urls integrated into index.html and the main app knows what to load then it needs to wait for events through postMessage API, one per each iframe.

The problem here is that the main app doesn't know if something goes wrong inside an iframe during initialisation stage: the service is down due to different reasons and the app isn't loaded inside an iframe, or the app inside an iframe lost a connection to the server or JS syntax error. The only way to detect that is just using a timeout, but that's not the best UX. A user will wait for example for 30 seconds before seeing an error.

Are there any possible ways to gain an access to iframes from the main window? May be by using CORS? It's clear for XHR requests but I haven't found info regarding iframes and CORS.

Comment: What sort of things can you change in the iframe? Everything, potentially?

Comment: I need as minimum get errors through `iframeEl.contentWindow.onerror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any possible ways to gain an access to iframes from the main window?

Only `postMessage`, which you are already using.

> May be by using CORS? It's clear for XHR requests but I haven't found info regarding iframes and CORS.

You cannot use CORS to grant cross origin access via frames.